# Simultaneous input from fifo and terminal in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdin, fifo

I am running ffmpeg inside a script and I want to be able to quit ffmpeg either by pressing 'q' in the terminal it's running in (default behaviour) or by inputting 'q' into a fifo file, whichever I happen to choose for that run of the program.

`ffmpeg </fifo_file` allows me to quit via the fifo file, however now no keyboard input is accepted. Conceptually I thought this would be a rather simple matter of then redirecting the input from the keyboard to the fifo, so that either way the input goes through the fifo and then into the stdin of ffmpeg.  But I have searched and found nothing.

It seems to me a pretty basic thing to be able to do for any command, not just ffmpeg: Combine two sources of input (key presses in terminal & input to fifo) into a single stdin. The specific order of terminal input>fifo>program I thought would be best so that the fifo would always be the ultimate source of input and not block.

I would appreciate a simple piece of bash script to perform the above and even better if there is a clear explanation of the pipe/redirection logic in it.